# How to set tf topic when take LRF on hand to build a map?

Tags: ros, navigation, scan, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm tring to use gmapping to build a map.

Before that,I try to record /scan and /tf.

If I want to just take the laser range finder on hand to build a map.

How do I set /tf topic correctly?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12855/how-to-set-tf-topic-when-take-lrf-on-hand-to-build-a-map?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2012-02-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As mentioned in my answer [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/2911/ros-mapping), there are two approaches available for scenarios where you do not have viable odometry data (which is the case for handheld mapping).

In case you want to try [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping) and you don't have a IMU, you can try these parameters:

```
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map" />
<param name="base_frame" value="laser_frame" />
<param name="odom_frame" value="laser_frame" />
```

with laser_frame being the frame your scan data has in it's header. Provided you hold the scanner steady (no roll and pitch motion, please ;) ) and the environment is largely rectangular, the system should work.

/edit: To make it more clear: The problem with the scenario you describe is not so much the tf setup itself (see the [tf tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/TF) for that), but the fact that you cannot provide odometry, which gmapping requires.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-02-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1